# Eye of Gnome - color washed out

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, color-management, eog

I'm having problems with Eye of Gnome, the image viewer. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately, the colors seems washed out, the images seem to lack contrast. This problem only happens with Eye of Gnome. If I use GIMP, Rawtherapee, Luminance HDR, ..., the colors are perfect.

I've used the following command: `xprop -root -remove _ICC_PROFILE`. This appears to temporarily fix the problem. When I start up the system again, Eye of Gnome is still affected by it. What can I do?